# Unable to programatically select a value in a Telerik RadDropDownList

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I have a form that has several 'RadDropDownList' objects that are bound to data sources. During the load event, I want to select a particular item from the list using the 'SelectedValue' property but it doesn't seem to be working. It always selects the first item in the list. Here is the code from the project;

```
Private Sub EditUser_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StoreDataSet.stores' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.StoresTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StoreDataSet.stores)
        'Load user data into form
        FirstNameTextBox.Text = FocusedUser.FirstName
        LastNameTextBox.Text = FocusedUser.LastName
        EmailTextBox.Text = FocusedUser.Email
        DealershipDropDownList.SelectedValue = FocusedUser.Store
        DepartmentDropDownList.SelectedValue = FocusedUser.Department
        PositionDropDownList.SelectedValue = FocusedUser.Position
        CellTextBox.Text = FocusedUser.Phone
        If FocusedUser.Carrier <> Nothing Then
            CarrierDropDownList.SelectedValue = FocusedUser.Carrier
        Else
            CarrierDropDownList.SelectedValue = 1
        End If
        If FocusedUser.StoreManager = True Then
            DealershipRadioButton.IsChecked = True
        ElseIf FocusedUser.DepartmentManager = True Then
            DepartmentRadioButton.IsChecked = True
        Else
            BasicRadioButton.IsChecked = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

The 'FocusedUser' class has data stored in it from a previous form. The 'ValueMember' of the 'RadDropDownList' objects are all integers and so are the values of the 'FocusedUser' fields in question. Can anyone help me determine why my 'RadDropDownList' objects aren't selecting the desired items on the 'Load'sub and point me in the right direction on how to fix it? Thanks!

NOTE: Only the "dealership" dropdownlist is bound right now. Once I can get that one working I can apply the fix to the others. Also attached is a screenshot showing the form after it loads. Notice the dealership dropdown list has data in it but its value doesn't change. Even if I move the statement to change the selectedvalue to a button event and call it later it never changes. If I use the ComboBox instead of a Telerik RadDropDownList it works perfectly.

[EditUserFormImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro0tJ.png)

Comment: I had a similar issue once with Telerik drop down lists, and what was odd about it is that normally selectedvalue worked for me everywhere but in the 'Load' sub....Is it possible for you to use "SelectedText" rather than "SelectedValue"? That is how I solved the issue.

Comment: If you pause execution where you're setting the selected value and look at the DDL's objects, does it actually have some? I think I had an issue like this and was trying to set selected item before the control even had items to select. Maybe I had to do it in the control's databound event?

Comment: @clweeks It does have a value before I try to set the selected value.

Comment: @GavinPerkins I would use the selctedtext but the displaymember and the valuemember hold different values. One holds text, the other holds an integer.

Comment: Please, show how and where in the code you set up `DataSource` for your `DropDownList`.

Comment: @Fabio the datasource is working correctly. When the app is run the drop down list has items to choose. The issue here is that programmatically selecting an item in the lists isn't working.

Comment: I affraid problem is that datasource was loaded after `SelectedValue` was set

Comment: If you look at the code above, you can see that the datasource is loaded BEFORE the SelectedValue is set. Or am I wrong?

Comment: What I was suggesting is that the datasource is loaded but not bound to the control during this event.

Comment: I edited my question so now there is an image to view. Also I added some info about calling the selectedvalue property in a button event after the form has loaded. Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example I put and the value is selected correctly:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("value");
        table.Columns.Add("name");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        table.Rows.Add(i, "name " + i);
        }

        radDropDownList1.DisplayMember = "name";
        radDropDownList1.ValueMember = "value";
        radDropDownList1.DataSource = table;

        radDropDownList1.SelectedValue = "5";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

`radDropDownList1.SelectedValue` had a data type of Decimal and my query was returning an integer value

DID NOT Change `SelectedValue`:

```
radDropDownList1.SelectedValue = dr("datavalue")
```

DID Change `SelectedValue`:

```
radDropDownList1.SelectedValue = CDec(dr("datavalue"))
```

It appears your types must match to make it work